# Do GWT Animations operate when they are called from a websocket?

Tags: java, javascript, animation, gwt, atmosphere

I'm trying to get a GWT animation to work from inside an atmosphere websocket callback but the animation never seems to start.

Here's my animation code..

```
public class SearchViewAnimation extends Animation
{
    private final Element element;
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int finalX;
    private int finalY;

    public SearchViewAnimation(Element element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void scrollTo(int x, int y, int milliseconds)
    {
        this.finalX = x;
        this.finalY = y;

        startX = element.getOffsetLeft();
        startY = element.getOffsetTop();

        run(milliseconds);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(double progress)
    {
        double positionX = startX + (progress * (this.finalX - startX));
        double positionY = startY + (progress * (this.finalY - startY));

        this.element.getStyle().setLeft(positionX, Style.Unit.PX);
        this.element.getStyle().setTop(positionY, Style.Unit.PX);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComplete()
    {
        super.onComplete();
        this.element.getStyle().setLeft(this.finalX, Style.Unit.PX);
        this.element.getStyle().setTop(this.finalY, Style.Unit.PX);
    }
}
```

and here is the code I use to call it...

```
public class SearchViewImpl extends Composite implements ISearchView {

    private static SearchViewImplUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(SearchViewImplUiBinder.class);
    @UiField AbsolutePanel Panel;

    interface SearchViewImplUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, SearchViewImpl> {
    }

    public SearchViewImpl() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void setNewUser(IUser user) {
        SearchElementImpl elem = new SearchElementImpl();
        elem.setUser(user);

        Panel.add(elem);

        SearchViewAnimation animation = new SearchViewAnimation(elem.getElement());
        animation.scrollTo(500, 500, 5000); 
    }
}
```

The fn setNewUser is called from the atmosphere websocket callback and executes roughly every ten seconds or so, however the animation never seems to actually move on the page, as I expect it too move via the scrollTo fn.  I have tested it inside a small GWT test project and the animation seems to work fine without the websocket.
 Does the web socket affect the usage of animation inside GWT code and if so does anyone know how to get a websocket to actually effect some animation?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out for some reason that you need to have

```
        Panel.setSize("500px", "500px");
        Panel.addStyleName("absolutePanel");
```

set somewhere for the animation to work.

Does anyone know..
a. how to set the size of an absolute panel the size of its containing panel
b. Why the style needs to be set on the absolute panel for animations to work?